# What are the pros and cons for opaque pointers vs id numbers using the C programming language?

Tags: c, encapsulation, library-design, memory-pool, opaque-pointers

I'm currently using opaque pointers as my standard technique for encapsulation, but looking at the OpenGL API makes me think that using id numbers could be a better choice. I would like some advice from seasoned C programmers (I've only been using the language actively for ~2 years).

Here are my initial thoughts that I would like confirmed or corrected.

**Possible pros for Id numbers:**

- Using object/memory pools in the implementation is rather straight forward if using id numbers
- The id number does not have to map to the system memory (could reference graphics memory in the GL case)

**Possible cons for Id numbers:**

- Makes the implementation slightly more complex

There is a similar question that takes into account the situation of using shared libraries:
[Should I use integer ID or pointers for my opaque objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323970/should-i-use-integer-id-or-pointers-for-my-opaque-objects)
My question is not about shared libraries, it's about the general case of hiding implementation details from user code.

I suppose you could typedef a MyObjectHandle to enable the library to switch between id number and opaque pointer.

The question is:
**What are the pros and cons for opaque pointers vs id numbers using the C programming language?**

Comment: "put on hold as primarily opinion-based" yes, I would like to hear some opinion on this subject. haha.... wtf?

Comment: changing title to Jeopardy! style. (formulated as a question)

Comment: Yes, SO is broken by design. Usually I find the most valuable answers in questions that were closed because of their broken rules. The problem is when a question gets closed before receiving answers, like in this case. I came this looking for answers on the topic you wrote.